# Having trouble with application

Tags: trigonometry

We are doing application problems in trigonometry and I am having trouble drawing a sketch from the words provided

The question is:

A captain knows that his ship is due south of a lighthouse. His destination is $20$km due west of the lighthouse, on a course setting $40$ degrees west of the lighthouse. How far south is the lighthouse from the ship?

Comment: How much could you do yourself? What did you draw? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

[image]![][]

The the value of $x$ only you have to find. I hope now this is easy to find.. Use you trignomety.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Base Angle = 40° and Rise = 20

Solution:

Base = $\frac{20} {tan(40 \text{ degrees})}$

Your answer is 23.8 km

You can aslo calculate

$\text{hypotenuse} = \frac{20}{sin(40\text{ degrees})} = 31.1144$